# Linq statements and System.ObjectDisposedException errors

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a query which retrieves some data within a context. I have a couple of other linq queries which also retrieve data within the same context. I then try to loop through the list of the first query and add objects from the second and third queries but I am getting the exception System.ObjectDisposedException later on when trying to access data.

For example:

```
var model = Activator.CreateInstance<M>();
using (IContext context = ContextFactory.GetContext(DatabaseType.Live))
{
    consignmentModel = (from c in context.Consignments
                    join ct in context.Contracts on c.ContractID equals ct.ID
                    where c.ManifestID == model.Manifest.ID
                    select new ConsignmentManifestModel
                    {
                        Consignment = c,
                        Contract = ct,                        
                    }).ToList(); 

    parcels = (from p in context.Parcels
               join pp in context.ParcelProducts on p.ID equals pp.ParcelID
               join c in context.Consignments on p.ConsignmentID equals c.ID
               where c.ManifestID == model.Manifest.ID
               select p).Include("ParcelProducts").ToList();

    parcelProducts = (from pp in context.ParcelProducts
                    join p in context.Parcels on pp.ParcelID equals p.ID
                    join c in context.Consignments on p.ConsignmentID equals c.ID
                    where c.ManifestID == model.Manifest.ID
                    select pp).ToList();
    ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    foreach(var c in consignmentModel)
    {
        var consignment = c.Consignment;
        consignment.SiteOrder = c.SiteOrder;
        consignment.Contract = c.Contract;
        foreach (var p in parcels)
        {
             if (p.ConsignmentID == consignment.ID)
             {                                                        
                  foreach (var pp in parcelProducts)
                  {                                                               
                      if (pp.ParcelID == p.ID) p.ParcelProducts.Add(pp);
                  }
                  consignment.Parcels.Add(p);
             }
        }
        model.Consignments.Add(consignment);
    }
    ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
}

:
:
:

foreach (var consignment in model.Consignments)
{
     foreach (var parcel in consignment.Parcels)  // ERROR - System.ObjectDisposedException
```

Comment: If you want lazy loading, then you need to keep your ObjectContext alive. Which means you can only access navigation properties *inside* your `using` statements.

Comment: is there any way to access navigation properties out the context?

Comment: No, either use LazyLoading and keep the context alive or use eager loading by using DataLoadOptions.LoadWith Method (System.Data.Linq):http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith(v=vs.110).aspx